# Value Error with a Matplotlib Candlestick Plot: too many pixels

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel, annotate, candlestick-chart

I am trying to overlay annotation on a matplotlib candlestick plot. But I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: Image size of 736485x402 pixels is too large. It must be
>   less than 2^16 in each direction.

My Jupyter Notebook code is below.

I am pulling Yahoo Earnings Calendar data into a dataframe, then transforming the DF into a numpy array, 'g2' with 4 columns).

When I only plot the candlestick, things work fine. But when I try to add annotation I get the error.

```
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime as datetime
import numpy as np



fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


plt.xticks(rotation=70)
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1,g2[:,0],g2[:,1],g2[:,2],g2[:,3],width=0.6,colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=1.0)
xdate = f2.index

ax1.annotate('Earnings Date 8-02', (xdate[30], g2[:,0][30]), xytext=( xdate[30], g2[:,0][30]), clip_on=True)


ax1.annotate("",
            xy=(xdate[30], 145), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(xdate[30], 150), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"),
            )


ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(6))

def mydate(x,pos):
    try:
        return xdate[int(x)]
    except IndexError:
        return ''

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

ax1.grid(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=45)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: The idea when reporting about an error is always the same: Provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that people are able to reproduce the error and hence are able to help you solve the issue.

Comment: That is always the problem here in stackoverflow: It is very easy to generate an error for a beginner, but creating an example data set which fullfills the reported issue, being at the same time an example, because your real world data is maybe confidental, is really challenging.